# How to use Parallel_coordinates from Pandas on a .txt file

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-coordinates

I'm trying to use parallel_coordinates from pandas on a .txt file and I have two issues:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_fwf
from pandas.tools.plotting import parallel_coordinates
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df= pd.read_fwf(rPathtoFile)
parallel_coordinates(df, "GTID")
plt.show()
```

1)Using this code, I get KeyError: "GTID" even though GTID is the name of the column in my .txt file that contains the class.(Sorry I can't share more of the file). My dataframe has loaded successfully, I checked through df.head()
[.txt file being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSOgd.png)

2) I only want to plot columns 4, 14, 15: is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please print `df.columns`, it will show you the exact column names. The column could be `" GTID"` with a leading space for instance.

Comment: A few comments to improve your question, by order of importance: a) please include your input data as text, not as an image; b) just format your code, do not make a snippet; c) quote the full error, and format it as a quote.

Comment: Alright, thank you. It's my first time so I needed that.

Comment: Why not use `df = pd.read_csv(rPathtoFile, sep='\t')`? It seems to be a tab seperated file.